# Why does java.awt.Point provide methods to set and get doubles but store x and y as int's?

Tags: java, awt, precision, point

As you can see in the Oracle Documentation for [java.awt.Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html), x and y are stored as `int`.  However, `getX` and `getY` return `double`.  While there is a `setLocation` method that takes 2 `double` types, there is no constructor that does.  Furthermore, the `double` gets truncated to an `int` internally anyway.

Is there a good reason for this?  You might avoid a cast on `setLocation` by having a method that takes `double` types, but you have the opposite problem when you call `getX` and `getY`.  There's also a misrepresentation of the precision of the Point class by returning a `double` from `getX` and `getY`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it extends from java.awt.geom.Point2D which is used in Graphics2D abstract class. It was implemented this way for compatibility reason since before this, java only supported java.awt.Graphics where all methods are int based.